# IntelliJ 2016 not copying logback.groovy when it is not in src/main/resources

Tags: intellij-idea

My IntelliJ (2016.1.1) does not copy `logback.groovy` from the path `conf/logback.groovy` inside some maven project. When located in `src/main/resources`, the file is instantly copied to the output folder. The `conf` folder is marked as resource folder. When renamed to e.g. `logback.groovy2` inside the `conf` folder, the file is also copied. I tried adding `logback.groovy` as resource pattern and exclude it from compilation, both to no avail.

All in all it seems that the `src/main/resource` folder has a special role in an idea maven project (compared to other resource folders). I presume that some maven configuration is required.

Answer (score 0):

Well, guess I found the solution myself. Adding

```
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>conf</directory>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</build>
```

to the `pom.xml` fixes the issue.